# How to prevent running tests when specific spring profile is active?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have a Spring Boot application build on Maven. I'm using Spring profiles to distinguish environment-specific configuration. I would like to prevent running tests when a specific Spring profile is active. Reason: I would like to prevent running tests with production properties (`spring.profiles.active=prod`). I would like to do this globally (maybe with some Maven plugin) instead of on each test separately.

Do you have any checked solutions for this?

Comment: Why don't you use `-DskipTests` in your build parameters. e.g. `mvc clean install -DskipTests=true`

Comment: That is not the case. I would like to prevent situation when someone run `mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=prod`

Answer (score 1):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: This relates to Maven profiles, not Spring profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@IfProfileValue` annotation. But you have to add some values to your active profile and read it with mentioned annotation. You can read more here (section 3.4.3): https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing

EDIT:
Another solution is to exclude all (or selected tests) tests in the Surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
         <exclude>${exclude.tests}</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
...
<profile>
  <id>prod</id>
  <properties>
    <exclude.tests>**/*.*</exclude.tests>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

And then when you run `mvn clean test -Pprod` all tests will be skipped

Comment: But I need to add the `@IfProfileValue` on each test. I do not want to do this.

Comment: @PiotrPradzynski I've updated my answer. Maybe second solution will help you somehow

Comment: Thanks, but this relates to Maven profiles, not Spring profiles.